# FluentWait for dynamically created ListBox

Tags: java, ajax, listbox, webdriver, fluent

I have a **listbox(droplist)** item that is created dynamically when I click on a div/span element .. However, when I try to click on the **listbox** element after doing a fluent Wait , it throws me an error  saying

> Element is not clickable at point (741, 192). Other element would receive the click:"

If i try to use `Thread.sleep(2000)`  then the code runs perfectly.  Any ideas on how I can fix this issue and make it work in `fluentWait`. I have tried *elementTobeClickable,elementSelectionStateToBe,presenceOfElementLocated* methods in the  *ExpectedConditions* class and they all throw the same error. I am using *ChromeDriver* for testing purposes .

My code and HTML snippet of the page is below

```
WebElement elt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='GroupTT']/span[2]/span/span[1]")); //Clicking on the span so that listbox will be activiated

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(elt).click().build().perform();       
fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='Group_listbox']/li[2]")))); //Thread.sleep(2000) works fine here.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='Group_listbox']/li[2]")).click();
```

HTML Snippet

```
<div >
<ul unselectable="on"  id="Group_listbox"  role="listbox" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-index="0"> Group1 </li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-index="1"> Group2 </li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-index="1"> Group3 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929195/webdriver-element-is-not-clickable-chrome

Comment: Saifru,I checked the link you mentioned and none of those solutions help me. I still have the same issues. More over I am trying to figure out why fluentWait does not work and if I am using the wrong methods of ExpectedConditions class

Comment: That seems like an issue with ChromeDriver itself. I ran into that before. Have you tested that on other browsers?

Comment: The Firefox browser design has some issues hence I am forced to use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the XPath locator to find the element by its inner text.

```
fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text() = 'Group2']"))));
```

Comment: I had the same issues when I tried your suggestion. However for now, the getText() at the end of fWait seems to be doing the trick. fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='Group_listbox']/li[2]")))).getText();